# Do you have to explicitly create instance of form in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, instance, explicit

If a project contains a `Form` class, can the form be shown by:

```
Form1.Show
```

or does an instance of the form need to be created first?

```
Dim frm As New Form1
frm.Show
```

Answer (score 8):

As has been suggested, using the form name uses the default instance while you second snippet explicitly creates an instance.  In both cases there is an instance of the form class; it's just a matter of whether the system creates it for you or you create it yourself.

Default instances did not exist in VB.NET until VB 2005, which was the third version.  They were added to make the transition from VB6 easier because some VB6 developers were confused by having to explicitly create objects.  They managed to create new confusion though, because it meant that forms seemed to behave differently to other types.  Also, some people tried to use default instances in multi-threaded applications and that creates issues because default instances are thread-specific.

There's generally no point implementing a singleton pattern for forms in VB.NET because default instances do that for you.  The only advantage to a genuine singleton would be that it would not be thread-specific.  It's also worth noting that, if the application framework is enabled for your project, which it is by default, the startup form is the default instance of its type.

Personally, I would never use a default instance unless I wanted singleton functionality.  What it does do for you is make it easier to access members of forms from other forms but anything like that that requires a default instance to achieve is bad practice anyway.

You might like to check out a couple of my blog posts for information on default instances and how to communicate between forms without them:

http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html
http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html

Make sure that you read all three parts of the second one.

To answer the question of how to implement the singleton pattern:

```
Public Class Form1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The one and only instance.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared _instance As Form1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the one and only instance.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As Form1
        Get
            'If there is no instance or it has been destroyed...
            If _instance Is Nothing OrElse _instance.IsDisposed Then
                '...create a new one.
                _instance = New Form1
            End If

            Return _instance
        End Get
    End Property

    'The only constructor is private so an instance cannot be created externally.
    Private Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

End Class
```

You then interact with Form1 only via the Instance property, e.g.

```
Form1.Instance.Show()
Form1.Instance.Activate()
```

That ensures that the one and only instance is displayed and has focus.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it can, it is the [default Form instance](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html) it was left in the Language for VB6 compatability.  If it was me I would avoid it like the plague, it only muddies the waters. Create your own instances instead.

Comment: It wasn't "left in".  VB.NET was built from the ground up so everything it contains was added.  Default instances didn't exist in VB.NET until 2005, which was the third iteration.  One thing I think we do both agree on is that the feature has caused as many problems as it has solved.